# Convert Join SQL to LINQ-to-SQL Method Syntax

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a repository for a MVC 4 Web API to retrieve data from database using Linq to SQL Method Syntax. The code I have so far (its not much) for the a utility:

```
public IQueryable<Vehicle> Vehicles(int driverId_Vehicles)
{
    ...?...
}
```

I've put together an SQL query that would get the data from the database:

```
SELECT VEHICLE.*
FROM Vehicle
INNER JOIN DriverHabit
ON VEHICLE.Id=DriverHabit.VehicleId
WHERE DriverHabit.Id = driverId
```

I need assistance translating this query into the LINQ method syntax to return the IQueryable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the association `Vehicle` - `DriverHabit` is 1:n. There should be a navtigation property `DriverHabits` in your `Vehicle` class, so you don't have to join. Just access the navigation property.

Comment: DriverHabit is a join table between Driver and Vehicle. A Driver does have many DriverHabits, but each DriverHabit has one and only one Vehicle. In the DriverHabit table, DriverId is a Foreign Key from the Id field in Driver, and VehicleId is a Foreign Key from the Vehicle table.

Comment: OK, so go for it! Use the navigation property and let linq-to-sql worry about joins.

Comment: Oh! I followed a tutorial on using Entity Framework and I didn't realize, but I already have the navigation property setup, I just didn't know how to use it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT VEHICLE.*
FROM Vehicle
INNER JOIN DriverHabit
ON VEHICLE.Id=DriverHabit.VehicleId
WHERE DriverHabit.Id = driverId

```
var vehicle = from v in _context.vehicle              
          join dh in _context.driverhabit on v.Id equals dh.VehicleId
          where dh.Id = driverId
          select { v, dh }

return vehicle.ToList();
```

Comment: There is no "select" after the where, and ToList() should be changed to Queryable(), but this is in the right direction. This, however, is SQL syntax, not method syntax.